# Calculate size in bytes of JSON payload including it in the JSON payload in PHP

Tags: php, json, associative-array

I have to send data using JSON in a structure like this:

```
$JSONDATA= 
    array(
        'response' => true, 
        'error' => null,
        'payload' => 
            array(
                'content' => $content,
                'size' => $size 
                )
        );
```

NOTE: the variable $content is a dynamic associative array, so its size is not constant.
The JSON output is sent using the classical system:

```
$joutput=json_encode($JSONDATA,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
echo $joutput;
```

The question is: how can I evaluate the variable $size dynamically and include it in the output?

Comment: You can't reliably embed the size of a string in the string *as* a string because that data will change the length of the string and the length of the string will change that data. Use the `Content-Length:` HTTP header instead.

Comment: it isn't so @Sammitch. 
See my solution below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use this to calculate `$content`'s size([DEMO](https://3v4l.org/L5vFk)):

```
$size = strlen(json_encode($content, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK));
```

This will provide you with the whole length of `json_encode()`d string of `$content`. If you want to calculate the size in bytes(if using multibyte characters), this might be more helpful([DEMO](https://3v4l.org/P1g9F)):

```
$size = mb_strlen(json_encode($content, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK), '8bit');
```

Comment: It worked fine, @mega6382 !
This is my solution: 

`$t = mb_strlen(json_encode($JSONDATA, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK), '8bit');
$JSONDATA['payload']['size']=$t+strlen($t);`

The result is perfect!

Comment: just mentioned your great solution in my last post. Your solution is now accepted!

Answer (score 3):

I guess this will be useful for many others, so I decided to answer to my own question using @mega6382 solution:

```
// prepare the JSON array 
$JSONDATA= 
array(
    'response' => true, 
    'error' => null,
    'payload' => 
        array(
            'content' => $content,
            'size' => $size 
            )
    );
// evaluate the JSON output size WITHOUT accounting for the size string itself
$t = mb_strlen(json_encode($JSONDATA, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK), '8bit');
// add the contribution of the size string and update the value
$JSONDATA['payload']['size']=$t+strlen($t);
// output the JSON data
$joutput=json_encode($JSONDATA,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
echo $joutput;
```

Answer (score 1):

Part 1. If this doesn't work for you, I'll update the answer after your next error.

```
$test_1 = memory_get_usage();
$content = array('key'=>'value');
$size = memory_get_usage() - $test_1;

$JSONDATA= 
    array(
        'response' => true, 
        'error' => null,
        'payload' => 
            array(
                'content' => $content,
                'size' => $size 
                )
        );
```

Comment: Well Giorgi, I've many thanks for your interesting reply, I've tried it and I get a result but unfortunately the numbers are wrong. In other words if I measure the output using the Chrome inspector I get 664 chars (or bytes) but using your method I get only 227 bytes...any clue?